# How do delete/remove a line using vim script

Tags: vim

According to http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#function-list vim script has functions setline() and append() to modify the current buffer but how do i delete a line from within a script? With setline(1, "") the line is only emptied but I want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use the ex command [:d](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:delete).  `:5d` deletes line 5.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled why there is no API function for doing something so important but apart from that

'exe ":1," . lastline . "d"'

does everything I want (actually I wanted to delete a whole range of lines).

Comment: Because there's no need for a function to do that.  You have a command that can do it.  Vimscript is a base of all the ex commands normally available plus additional functions to provide functionality that isn't available (or easily available) through the ex commands.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to delete a line without affecting the undo list, though.

Answer (score 9):

One addition: don’t do `execute line 'delete'`, do `execute line 'delete _'`: deleting to black hole register has a minimal number of side-effects. Without `_` it will delete to default register, numbered register `1` and will move all other numbered registers (except `0` which is for yanks): `1`->`2`, `2`->`3`, …, `9`->void.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ahe
1delete
%delete
1,$delete
```

no need for execute here